# Does conditional independence imply the following identities?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, econometrics, conditional-independence

I was reading this paper https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.143.8127&rep=rep1&type=pdf , and it heavily uses conditional independencies for deriving various identities, which I could not check by myself if they are correct.

Let me ask three closely related ones that particularly seemed non-trivial (I simplified the problem ).
Let S,G, X be random variables, where G is binary and others are in general continuous. 
Assume $ S \amalg G |X $ but not necessarily $ Y \amalg G |X$ Is the following three identities always true? Prove or disprove by counterexample.\

(i) $E[Y | X, G=1] = E[Y|X, S,G=1] $
(ii) $ E[Y|X, S,G=1] = E[Y|X, S,G=0] $
(iii) $E[g(S,G) ] = E[ E[g(S,G) | G, X] ] = E[ E[ g(S,G) |X] ]$
Although I failed to prove these, my thoughts on if true, how they may possibly be proved:
The operations that you probably need in proving this
1. bayes rule
2. law of total probability 
3. law of iterated expectation 
For example, I tried to prove (ii) by using bayes rule as in
(left hand) = $\int y p(y,s| x,g=1)/p(s|x,g=1) = p(y,x|x,g=1)/p(s|x,g=0)  (\because S \amalg G |X) $ but I don't think the g=1 in the numerator can be switched to g=0? 
I hope this showed my attempts.

Comment: Did you attempt to (dis)prove the given identities? Please make sure you specify your attempted works in the question or even the approach you think that is relevant here.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I gave my comments on some of my atttempts, and the possible approaches. I've just started learning probability theory so hope I'm not that off :|